# PyTorch - How to get learning rate during training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

While training, I'd like to know the value of learning_rate.
What should I do?

It's my code, like this:

```
my_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(my_model.parameters(), 
                               lr=0.001, 
                               momentum=0.99, 
                               weight_decay=2e-3)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For only one parameter group like in the example you've given, you can use this function and call it during training to get the current learning rate:

```
def get_lr(optimizer):
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        return param_group['lr']
```

Comment: Set the lr to 0.1 on SGD with no momentum nor scheduler. Got 7.2 something during the traing. I don't think the value shown is correct

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you may use an `lr_scheduler` along with your optimizer and simply call the built-in `lr_scheduler.get_lr()` method.

Here is an example:

```
my_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam( my_model.parameters(), 
                                 lr = 0.001, 
                                 weight_decay = 0.002)

my_lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR( my_optimizer, 
                                                step_size = 50, 
                                                gamma = 0.1)

# train
...
my_optimizer.step()
my_lr_scheduler.step()

# get learning rate
my_lr = my_lr_scheduler.get_lr()
# or
my_lr = my_lr_scheduler.optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']
```

The added benefit for using `lr_scheduler` is more controls on changing lr over time; lr_decay, etc.
For lr_scheduler args, refer to pytorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. But you can use `scheduler._last_lr` and it will give you like `[0.001]`

Comment: Pytorch 2.0 is `scheduler.get_last_lr()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
optimizer.param_groups[-1]['lr']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As of PyTorch 1.13.0, one can access the list of learning rates via the method `scheduler.get_last_lr()` - or directly `scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]` if you only use a single learning rate.

Said method can be found in the schedulers' base class `LRScheduler` ([See their code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L104-L107)). It actually returns the attribute `scheduler._last_lr` in the base class as Zahra has mentioned but calling the method should be more preferred.

Edit: Thanks @igorkf for the reply

Comment: This method returns a list of one element, so you have to do `scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]`

Answer (score 1):

As I read through the source code of [torch.optim.Optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/optimizer.html#Optimizer) and one of its subclasses, say [torch.optim.Adam](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/adam.html#Adam), it is clear to me that the `lr` is stored in a dictionary named `defaults` in the subclass, and then this dictionary is passed into the `__init__` method of the base class, which is the `Optimizer` class, along with `params`. Upon receiving the arguments, the base class then saves `defaults` into its own attribute with the same name. Here is a small fraction of its source code:

```py
def __init__(self, params, defaults):
    torch._C._log_api_usage_once("python.optimizer")
    self.defaults = defaults
    ...
```

Therefore, to retrieve the value of the learning rate from a torch's optimizer, I believe the solution would be:

```py
optimizer.defaults['lr']
```