# conversion form Tensorflow to pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_lr, global_step, 3000, 0.96, staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr, epsilon=0.1)

I want this tensorflow code to be converted to Pytorch

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? You can easily search for Pytorch Adam Optimizer, for example, and find out how it's constructed.

Answer (score 0):

```
args.learning_rate = 0.001 i.e. start_lr
args.learning_rate_decay_factor = 0.96
args.learning_rate_decay_step = 3000

optim = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)

lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer=optim, gamma=args.learning_rate_decay_factor,last_epoch=-1)

for epoch in (range(1, args.num_epoch + 1)):
   
    # Do Forward pass here
    
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
  
    if epoch % args.learning_rate_decay_step == 0:
        lr_scheduler.step()
    # debugging purpose
    print(lr_scheduler.get_last_lr()) # will print last learning rate.
```

The training process will update learning rate every 3000 epoch.

Hope this answers your question, let me know otherwise. This is my first answer so your feedback will help me improve future answers. :)

References:

- [PyTorch - How to get learning rate during training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660985/pytorch-how-to-get-learning-rate-during-training)
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-torch-optim-lr-scheduler-exponentiallr/12444/6